# Storage of images for a cache or SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, caching, bitmap, storage

I am writing my first app, and this is probably a stupid question, but one that I've found is unclear.

1: If I'm using a LRU cache for bitmaps, where are the image files stored? (ie. What folder would they be stored in?)

2: If I'm using a SQLite database of bitmaps, where are the image files stored? (same question as above but for SQLite)

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: 1. you mean http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/util/LruCache.html ? then in memory 2. `a SQLite database of bitmaps` have no f* idea what you are talking about ... but if images are stored as BLOB in SQLite then they are stored in (drums!!!) SQLite ... but if the images are stored as links to the file/media library url then somewhere on device storage ...

Answer (score 0):

If you use LRU cache for bitmaps, you can use **Memory Cache** with [LruCache](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/LruCache.html) class or **Disk Cache** with [DiskLruCache](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/jb-mr2-release/luni/src/main/java/libcore/io/DiskLruCache.java). Please see the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html). Using Disk Cache you can save a bitmaps on internal or external storage.
Otherwise, using Sqlite, the bitmaps are saved on database file for security reasons, is recommended store sqlite database on internal storage.

Comment: It sounds like I need to do more research into what internal and external storage are. Thanks for the reply, I will look into that!